# Downloading a file from a html? url with python 3

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, networking, ftp

I've been searching for hours on how to download a file [the documentation](ftp://ftp.tor.ec.gc.ca/Pub/Get_More_Data_Plus_de_donnees/Readme.txt) shows me how to do this; but  cygwin is horrible and an annoyance to use and I'm trying to implement this in Python 3 for a program. I've tried to use urllib, requests, wget(in python), httplib and some other. But it only fetched the redirected page (as you would get if you paste the link in the url bar with the properly formatted url.)

Though when I inspect a page and I trigger the download link that has the same address that I tried, it works properly and provide me with a download pop-up. [Here is an example page](http://climate.weather.gc.ca/climate_data/daily_data_e.html?hlyRange=%7C&dlyRange=1960-11-01%7C1962-12-31&mlyRange=1960-01-01%7C1962-12-01&StationID=703&Prov=BC&urlExtension=_e.html&searchType=stnProv&optLimit=yearRange&StartYear=1840&EndYear=2017&selRowPerPage=25&Line=16&Month=12&Day=9&lstProvince=&timeframe=2&Year=1962) the link is triggered by clicking "Download data"

I don't get how any python package is unable to send the proper get request and that I would need to implement this program in linux only to be able to use 'wget'.

Anyone has a clue on how to properly call the url?

Comment: You tried urllib.requests? (urllib.requests.retreive))

Comment: As stated I tried urllib.request.urlretreive

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `&submit=Download+Data` to the end of your URL to download the data. You can see this with the network tab of inspect element in google chrome. Hope I helped!

Comment: I use Src="http://climate.weather.gc.ca/climate_data/bulk_data_e.html?format=csv&stationID={stat}&Year={yr}&Month={moth}&Day={day}&timeframe={tf}&submit=Download+Data".format(stat=stt,yr=Yr,mth=mss,day=Day,tf=TimeF)

src is the input for my query request that I tried with any library, and it didn't work, it always redirected me to the main page.

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
from subprocess import call

def download(URL)
      CMD = ['curl',url]
      call(CMD)
```

to run this:

```
download('www.download.com/blah/bah/blah')
```

if you want to use this from the interpreter:
save as module.py

```
python -i /path/to/module.py

>>>download('www.download.com/blah/bah/blah')
```

p.s. if this works i'll prob use this in my shell program

EDIT: my comment:

I tried this and got "malformed url" error

```
from subprocess import call
def download(FILE,URL):
    #FILE = file to save to
    #URL - download from here
    CMD = ['curl','-o',FILE,URL]
    call(CMD)
```

this is what i do for all system commands from python so its something to do with curl specifically.

Comment: With vanilla curl it doesn't work, maybe with some option and by sending the proper header or with the right option it might work, but even with a valid and invalid request it shows the same response. but I got one good response with urllib just now.

Comment: ok idk how to do code in a comment im just ganna re right it in my answer

Comment: my suggestion would be to get familiar with curl from bash (i'm not) then you'll know how to make it work in python just set the command to a variable name CMD(cant do spaces with call tho it has to be a list like i have in my answer)

Comment: and i think Bluecode is prob right about puting "&submit=Download+Data" at the end of the url but idk html so i dont know if it needs a / between them or what

Comment: Honestly from what I saw curl accepts url but doesn't accept a the equivalent of the file field.

Comment: As stated previously, my url already had the Download+Data parameter in the URL request, the main issue was mostly formatting since I forgot syntax changes between bash and python formatting. The query is located after the ? and the & link parameters and the assigned values together..